# Aggregate when local field is a key in array of object from another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was trying get to get the count of element that is present in the array of objects in another collection.

Example:

#Collection A:

```
{
   _id:1,
   name:"Sample1"
}
{
  _id:2,
  name:"Sample 2"
}
{
  _id:3,
  "name":"Sample 3"
}
{
  _id:4,
  "name":"Sample 4"
}
```

#Collection B:

```
{
   _id:11,
   items:[ {_id:1, name:"sample1",size:1},{_id:3, name:"sample 3",size:5}]
}
{
   _id:12,
   items:[ {_id:1, name:"sample1",size:2},{_id:3, name:"sample 3",size:6}]
}
{
   _id:13,
   items:[ {_id:2, name:"sample2", size:5},{_id:1, name:"sample 1",size:8}],
is_delete:true
}
{
   _id:14,
   items:[ {_id:1, name:"sample1",size:3},{_id:3, name:"sample 3",size:1}]
}
```

> Note: The _id in items is string.

#Expected Output:

```
{
   _id:1,
   name:"Sample1",
  count:6
}
{
  _id:2,
  name:"Sample 2",
  count:0
}
{
  _id:3,
  "name":"Sample 3",
  "count":12
}
{
  _id:4,
  "name":"Sample 4",
  "count":0
}
```

Please help me to write a mongo query to get the expected out put.

Comment: Will the actual data look like this? or will there be an exact match between the names? i.e `Sample 1` !== `sample1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$lookup` join with collection2, let to pass _id as string and add pipeline, to match _id with items._id and is_delete not true,
- `$addFields` to get total size of `count` array element using `$size`

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection2",
      let: { id: { $toString: "$_id" } },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            is_delete: { $ne: true },
            $expr: {
              $ne: [
                [],
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$items",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$id", "$$this._id"] }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "count"
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { count: { $size: "$count" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xocbFwSbVgZ)

Comment: Hi Turivishal your answer worked great for me. But I forgot to add few more conditions (in B collection) in the questions. Now I updated the question. If have time please look at this once.

Comment: Hi Turivishal sorry for editing my question again. If you have time please look at once.

Comment: You can check updated answer. just added $toString operator to convert

Comment: Turivishal i added one more field for items in collection B. Count should be calculated based on the size that present in items array.

Comment: Its different question why can't you prefer to ask new question instead of edit. i will answer you there.

Comment: Hi turivishal asked new question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64734988/aggregation-with-multiple-criterias-and-sum-match-based-on-the-count-key