# Aggregation with multiple criteria's and sum match based on the count key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was trying get to get the count of element that is present in the array of objects in another collection.
Example:

Collection A:

```
{
   _id:1,
   name:"Sample1"
}
{
  _id:2,
  name:"Sample 2"
}
{
  _id:3,
  "name":"Sample 3"
}
{
  _id:4,
  "name":"Sample 4"
}
```

Collection B:

```
{
   _id:11,
   items:[ {_id:1, name:"sample1",size:1},{_id:3, name:"sample 3",size:5}]
}
{
   _id:12,
   items:[ {_id:1, name:"sample1",size:2},{_id:3, name:"sample 3",size:6}]
}
{
   _id:13,
   items:[ {_id:2, name:"sample2", size:5},{_id:1, name:"sample 1",size:8}],
is_delete:true
}
{
   _id:14,
   items:[ {_id:1, name:"sample1",size:3},{_id:3, name:"sample 3",size:1}]
}
```

Note: The _id in items is string.

Expected Output:

```
{
   _id:1,
   name:"Sample1",
  count:6
}
{
  _id:2,
  name:"Sample 2",
  count:0
}
{
  _id:3,
  "name":"Sample 3",
  "count":12
}
{
  _id:4,
  "name":"Sample 4",
  "count":0
}
```

Please help me to write a mongo query to get the expected out put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are two collections, we need to use

- `$lookup` to join tow collections. Here I used [uncorelated subqueries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)
- The aggregation is performed in `colA` collections, but inside the `lookup`'s `pipeline` we perform aggregation on `colB`. `$unwind` helps to de-structure the `items`. `$match` helps to eliminate unwanted data (match stage requires [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#op._S_expr)).
- Once our join is succeeded, we need to just count the array using `$size`
- `$reduce` helps to sum the array value of `size`

The mongo script is given below.

```
db.colA.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "colB",
      let: {
        bid: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $or: [
              {
                is_delete: false
              },
              {
                is_delete: {
                  "$exists": false
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$items"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$items._id",
                "$$bid"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        
      ],
      as: "data"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $add: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.items.size"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EiOjJkvwg6R)**

Comment: Hi Varman, I think you missed to consider size key and is_delete keys in collection B.